# Allow moderators to see which comments are for deleted posts, on admin/users/<user id>/post-comments?state=all

Tags: feature-request, comments, users, moderator-tools

When I look at `admin/users/<user id>/post-comments?state=all`, I cannot see which comments are for deleted posts.

Could be possible to add a different background for the comments on deleted posts?

What I actually see is shown in the following screenshot, where it is not evident the last comment is for a deleted post.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Comments that were deleted *as comments* get the pink background now, but comments that are deleted as a result of being attached to *deleted posts* are not.  I'd like to see those show up as deleted too. (Whether this is a separate state from the former I leave to others; I just want to know, without clicking, if this comment is live on the site.)